# how to set a new auto increment value in existing table field?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

i have a table with a `order_id` field set to auto increment. Its currently about at `325`

but i need to start all the newly added entries to start off with `1000,1001.....` rather than continuing with `326`.

i need to keep the existing IDs the same and change only the newly adding values.

can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```